# Finding weight/value of each person on a team

Tags: algorithms, graphs

If I have a team, with between $n_1$ and $n_2$ people per team, with results of team's head to head matchups, how would I be able to estimate each person's value?

Example data (I drew this up quickly, the actual one is many lines longer):

```
| Home   | Away   | Home Score | Away Score | Home Members  | Away Members     |
| ------ | ------ | ---------- | ---------- | ------------- | ---------------- |
| Team 1 | Team 2 | 4          | 2          | John, Joe     | Mary, James      |
| Team 1 | Team 3 | 3          | 2          | Joe, Patricia | Mark, Paul, Ross |
| Team 2 | Team 5 | 1          | 2          | Mary, Robert  | Steve, Lisa      |
| Team 4 | Team 3 | 4          | 3          | Ashley        | Mark, Matt       |
| Team 4 | Team 5 | 2          | 3          | Donna, Emily  | Anne, Lisa       |
```

For the example data, I want to be able to say something like `John` is the best with a individual score of $s_1$ and `Mary` is right behind him with a individual score of $s_2$ and `James` is the worst with a score of $s_n$.

We define $s_1 \geq s_2 \geq \ldots \geq s_n$ (although it is almost guaranteed that $s_1 > s_n$). We should be able to say that a team of `John` and `Mary` will beat any other team of 2. We should also be able to say that if we replace any Person1 with Person2 on TeamX, TeamX will do better if $s_{\textrm{Person1}} < s_{\textrm{Person2}}$, worse if $s_{\textrm{Person1}} > s_{\textrm{Person2}}$, and equally as well if $s_{\textrm{Person1}} = s_{\textrm{Person2}}$.

This means that we cannot have one person "carried" by their team. For example, we cannot give `Joe` an unreasonably high $s_{\textrm{Joe}}$ just because he was on a team with `John` who scores very well. This is the problem with most simplistic algorithms (such as ELO). Going into a little more detail as to why this is a problem, let us take ELO as an example. Let us say that `John` and `Patricia` are both strong players. Even if `Joe` is a bad player, he would have a high score by ELO. However, the ideal system should somehow differentiate good players from players on good teams. This is the crux of the problem.

This seems fairly trivial, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to do it. Any method I create seems to have circular reasoning, as if I update one person's value than it means that everyone on their teams falls (the team is only so good, so each person's score on the same team is necessarily zero sum), which then comes back to update the original person's value, which causes updates to everyone else, and so on.

Comment: How do you plan to define "value"?  That sounds like something that is not a computer science question, and that would have to be determined before this could be formulated as a question about computer science.  So, the question doesn't seem well-posed or suitable here yet.  It will presumably require a model for how the team's overall results are affected by the players.  In real life, that may not be a simple relationship, so any model will be a simplification; you'll have to choose what simplifications you do and don't want to make.

Comment: @D.W. Value would be what the people each contribute to the team. For example, we can say that `Team 1` has a value of `79` (they will beat anyone with a value less than that and lose to anyone with a value more than that); the team's individual player's values are the amount they contribute to the teams value. In the example, `John` would help any team he joins as a replacement for any other person. In essence, it's an empirical way of calculating the MVP of the league but for every position, not just the 1st; it would be the model for how the team's results are affected by player.

Comment: That's not a definition of value, that's an English sentence that describes what you hope it would achieve.  We need a mathematical definition or something precise that would allow us to calculate the value.  I'm highlighting that defining "value" is trickier than I think you may have realized.

Comment: @D.W. I'm a little confused. Why does value have to be pre-defined? I was hoping for something like the ELO system, but broken down by person on the team instead of team as a whole. Can the definition of value not stay the same then?

Comment: If you're asking what rating system to use or how to define a rating system, I'm not sure that's a question about computer science; it sounds like a question about statistics or data modeling to me.  You could probably adapt the Bradley-Terry model, or just run Elo where you credit a win to each player on the winning team and a loss to each player on the losing team.  If you're asking how to compute a rating defined by a particular rating system, that's on-topic, but maybe not what you're asking.

Comment: @D.W. My question is along the lines of if someone asked "how to rate teams who don't play everyone head-to-head" and the answer would have been `ELO system`. It sounds like the would be "defining a rating system", but I assumed that would be allowed here. If it is, how can I restructure my question to make it clearer? If not, should I delete the question?

Comment: Related: online multiplayer team games generalize Elo (dota 2, league of legends).  I believe Dota 2's system is very similar to Elo, but using an aggregate team A elo vs team B elo to perform updates (aggregate is something like avg of the team's elos).  Then the Elo update applies to each individual (e.g. -25 to all on losing team, +30 to all on winning team).

Comment: @KevinWang Correct, but that method has many flaws (ex. one person's value could be "carried" by his team). Hence the search for a better method

Comment: Perhaps you could [edit] the question to tell us about what methods you've considered, why you've rejected them, and what criteria you will use to evaluate proposed answers?

Comment: @D.W. Updated. Is this clearer?

Comment: @qag54938bcaoo that is definitely more well-defined. However, you say that we want to assign a value to each player, but you haven't explained how, given player values of two teams, we determine who should win.  I'm guessing you want to either `avg` or `sum` each team and then compare the two resulting values.  I also find it strange that this formulation asserts the impossibility of an upset in the data, which is not representative of real life (and the reason that Elo compares two scores and outputs a probability of victories, not a sure victor).  Is this intended?

Comment: @KevinWang Inherently there will be some sort of probability matrix. Whether we decide to output the percentages or the expected victor is a personal choice I think. Correct, if we are making a virtual team (ie. players that are not already on a team), we would compare `sum` or `avg` (I'm leaning more towards sum, although this is trivial) to determine who we think would win.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/126051/755, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/467848/2921.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was cross-posted.